# How to show all apps on an Android phone?

Tags: applications, huawei, xiaomi, emui

I had a [Huawei Mate 9](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_mate_9-8073.php) before, and there was an icon at the bottom-center of the screen, so that when I tap it, it shows all apps on the phone. (It is running the latest Android it can, which I think is Android 9 and EMUI 9.1)

However, I just got a [Xiaomi Redmi 9](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_9-10233.php), and there seems to be no such icon (it is running Android 10 and MIMU 11). I can only slide the desktop left and right.

Is the standard Android interface actually to show all apps by default on the desktop (and is slide-able, like on an iPhone), and so there is no need to have that bottom-center icon, and we actually can see all apps on the phone just by sliding the desktop left and right?

Comment: Note that what you describe of your new phone is proprietary behavior implemented by Xiaomi. Other Android devices don't work this way. On recent Google phones there is also no icon to show all apps, instead you can swipe from the bottom up to open this list. If you don't like the launcher behavior you can simply change it by installing a different launcher app from Play Store.

Comment: That icon in your earlier phone launched a screen commonly known as "App Drawer". I think Xiaomi's default launcher does offer app drawer. It offers two skins. One is more like iphone style, one is traditional Android style. Try long pressing in empty space on your homescreen and see if you get any option to customize settings. Look into it. If you get a relevant option, fine then. Else, you've got to change your launcher app. Nova Launcher and many other launchers offer a direct button for app drawer.